# Location of twentyeleven theme's option filters?

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven

Hi I'm learning theming options based on the existing theme TwentyEleven.

I've come across the following code in inc/theme-options.php

```
return apply_filters( 'twentyeleven_default_theme_options', $default_theme_options );
```

I can't seem to find the add_filter for 'twentyeleven_default_theme_options', or does it not even exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there *is* an `add_filter()` call anywhere. If you want to override the option defaults, you can call your own `add_filter()` to do so, either in a Plugin or in a Child Theme.

**EDIT**

An `apply_filters()` call is nothing more than a *filter hook definition*: basically, it is defining the data to which a filter hook is applied.

It is similar to `do_action()`, which is an *action hook definition*: it defines the template location/runtime execution point at which the action hook is fired.

So, the presence of `apply_filters()` **does not imply** that there will necessarily be a corresponding `add_filter()` call; rather, it merely means that a filter is **available** to modify the specified data.

On the *other hand*, the presence of `add_filter()` **does imply** that somewhere, a corresponding `apply_filters()` call exists - just as the presence of an `add_action()` call implies that somewhere, a corresponding `do_action()` call exists.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner at this. From what I read from the codex, it seems like you need to add the filter before you can apply it. But in this case the add_filter portion is missing, how does the apply_filter work?

Comment: See updated answer. You've got it a bit backward. :)

Comment: Thanks alot. I'm currently reading your post on how to incorporate the settings api, and it really helps alot!

Answer (score 0):

`apply_filters` is required if you want to define your own filters, or wrap the existing ones with your custom filters. That's what is happening in the code you saw. You won't need to add any custom filters at a beginner stage, so won't need to use `apply_filters`, at least until you get comfortable with the existing ones! WordPress provides you with a huge list of filters, check [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) for a category wise list of filters and how to use them. Start digging into these.